# Using a function to make a "folded list"

Tags: python, function

*Very, very little python background here - this is my first week in a 5-week cram course on it.
I need to make a function that takes a list as input and makes the list "folded in half" so that the first term is added to the last term, the second term is added to the second to last, etc.

I was able to make a code that did this - but realized afterward that it wasn't a function like I'm supposed to make.

Here is the code that I made that works:
`a = [10, 14, 21, 25 ,52, 55]`
`foldedlist=[ a[i] + a[-(i + 1) ] for i in range( len(a) // 2)]`
`print('folded list:', foldedlist)`

But I was vaguely told that I'm supposed to make something more like this:
`def folded_list(input_list):`
`<stuff here>`
`return <whatever you call the folded list>`

So I tried the code below instead, but all I get printed is
"<function folded_list at 0x7ff13cb174c0>"

`a=(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11)`
`def folded_list(a):`
   `(sum((a[i]) + (a[-(i + 1) ])) for i in range( len(a) // 2))`
  `return(folded_list)`
`print(folded_list)`

I'm confused about what to put in the "stuff here" line and whether it needs the greater/less than signs around it. Should I do a for loop like I had in my previous code? Or some other type of math?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is a way of reusing code. So lets say instead of just list `a` that you have now you have 10,000 lists that you want to fold. Without a function you would need to type your code 10,000 times changing `a` to the new list each time. What a function does instead is allows you to perform a set of code on demand. Now instead of typing your code 10,000 times you can just call your function.

Let's take a look at a basic function:

```
def foo(num):
    result = num * num
    return result
```

This function takes an input argument `num`(placed in the parenthesis of the function declaration) and returns the square of that number. Now if you run the following code you'll see why functions are useful:

```
def foo(num):
    result = num * num
    return result

print(foo(5)) #25
print(foo(11)) #121
print(foo(8)) #64
```

See? We only had to type the code once for calculating the square of a number!

Now lets go back to folding lists. What they are asking for is the following:

```
def folded_list(input_list):
    <stuff here>
    return <whatever you call the folded list>
```

The `<text>` is a common way of writing "fill in the blank" or MadLibs style. It is just a placeholder. So you will want something like:

```
a = [10, 14, 21, 25, 52, 55]
b = [58, 46, 78, 12]
c = [11, 64, 62, 50, 44, 31, 77, 99]

def folded_list(input_list):
    a = input_list
    folded_list_output = [ a[i] + a[-(i + 1) ] for i in range( len(a) // 2)] #your code
    return folded_list_output

print('folded list a:', folded_list(a)) #folded list a: [65, 66, 46]
print('folded list b:', folded_list(b)) #folded list b: [70, 124]
print('folded list c:', folded_list(c)) #folded list c: [110, 141, 93, 94]
```

Now you can run that same line of code as many times as you'd like! Hope this makes a bit more sense now :)

Now let's look at two possible ways to shorten the method without changing its function.

In the above example I have `a = input_list`, but even that isn't super necessary. You can do your operations directly on input_list as so:

```
def folded_list(input_list):
    folded_list_output = [ input_list[i] + input_list[-(i + 1) ] for i in range( len(input_list) // 2)]
    return folded_list_output
```

Which can be simplified even further by directly returning your calculation:

```
def folded_list(input_list):
    return [ input_list[i] + input_list[-(i + 1) ] for i in range( len(input_list) // 2)]
```

Comment: Yes, this was so helpful! Much more explanation than I had been given by anyone else so it actually makes sense. Thank you!!